# spark find which persons often go to the same counties

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

The data source is:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1,1]").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1").config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("error")
import spark.implicits._

val df=Seq(
  ("tom","America","2019"),
  ("jim","America","2019"),
  ("jack","America","2019"),
  ("tom","Russia","2019"),
  ("jim","Russia","2019"),
  ("jack","Russia","2019"),
  ("alex","Russia","2019"),
  ("tom","America","2018"),
  ("jim","America","2018"),
  ("tom","Germany","2018"),
  ("jim","England","2018")
).toDF("person","country","year")
```

I want to find which persons often go to the same countries for each year,and where they gone together,so what I expect is a json like this:

```
[{
        "year": "2019",
        "items": [{
            "persons": ["tom", "jim", "jack"],
            "common": ["America", "Russia"],
            "times": 2
        }, {
            "persons": ["tom", "jack"],
            "common": ["America", "Russia"],
            "times": 2
        }, {
            "persons": ["tom", "jim"],
            "common": ["America", "Russia"],
            "times": 2
        }, {
            "persons": ["jack", "jim"],
            "common": ["America", "Russia"],
            "times": 2
        }]
    },
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "items": [{
            "persons": ["tom", "jim"],
            "common": ["America"],
            "times": 1
        }]
    }

]
```

Then I am not sure what model shall I use?
I tried Frequent Items Pattern:

```
   val df1=df.where('year===2019)
   val rdd1= df1.groupBy("country").agg(collect_set('person)).drop("country","year")
    .as[Array[String]].rdd
      val fpg = new FPGrowth()
      .setMinSupport(0.3)
      .setNumPartitions(10)
       val schema = new StructType().add(new StructField("items", ArrayType(StringType))).add(new StructField("freq", LongType))
        val model = fpg.run(rdd1);
        val rdd2 = model.freqItemsets.map(itemset => Row(itemset.items, itemset.freq))
       val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema).where(size('items)>1)
           .show()
```

loop for every year

```
val df2=df.where('year===2018)
val rdd2= df1.groupBy("country").agg(collect_set('person)).drop("country","year")
        .as[Array[String]].rdd
....
val model = fpg.run(rdd12);
....
```

The result is :
for 2019

```
+----------------+----+
|           items|freq|
+----------------+----+
|     [jack, tom]|   2|
|[jack, tom, jim]|   2|
|     [jack, jim]|   2|
|      [tom, jim]|   2|
+----------------+----+
```

for 2018:

```
+----------+----+
|     items|freq|
+----------+----+
|[tom, jim]|   1|
+----------+----+
```

But I can not get when and where they gone together,becuase the `rdd` I give to `FPGRowth` must be a `RDD[Array[String]]`,no more columns allowed.
Is there any other better model?How can I  achieve it?

I also want to know how many times each person group go together

Maybe what I should use collaborative filtering

Answer (score 0):

Just self-join and aggregate

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.alias("left")
  .join(df.alias("right"), Seq("country", "year"))
  .where($"left.person" < $"right.person")
  .groupBy(array($"left.person", $"right.person").alias("persons"))
  .agg(collect_set(struct($"country", $"year")).alias("common"))
```

Comment: What about 3 person go to the same countries?So I need join itself 3 times.Or even 4 person or more go together?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("country", "year")
df
  .withColumn("persons", collect_set('person) over window)
  .drop('person)
  .distinct()
  .groupBy('persons)
  .agg(collect_set(struct('country, 'year)).alias("common"))
```

Output (tested):

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
|persons   |common                            |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|[jim, tom]|[[America, 2019], [Russia, 2019]] |
|[tom]     |[[Germany, 2018], [America, 2018]]|
|[jim]     |[[Russia, 2018], [England, 2018]] |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry,I made a bad example of data source.If "alex" also go to russia in 2019,then It is hard to see tom,jim,jack go together for 2 times.I descript  this in the addition info of the question

Comment: What do you mean by "hard to see"?

Comment: if I add a row("alex","Russia","2019")  and a column count(persons) in your result.[jim, jack, tom] counts 1,[jim, jack, tom, alex] count 1. it is hard to see that actually jim, jack, tom has gone to the same county in the same year for 2 times

Comment: I see. So, how would you like to see it?

Comment: I edited my question,I would like to see the json above